# React Native test with Jest and react-native-ble-plx library fails because "Jest encountered an unexpected token"

Tags: react-native, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

Trying to execute that must be a simple screen test, I found this error. I saw some related issues and solutions touching babel and jest config but I did not found the proper way to solve it.

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /Users/.../node_modules/react-native-ble-plx/index.js:3
    export { BleError, BleErrorCode, BleAndroidErrorCode, BleIOSErrorCode, BleATTErrorCode } from './src/BleError'
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally was solved adding it to `jest.config.js`:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(jest-)?@?react-native|@react-native-community|@react-navigation)',
  ],
```

Source: related issue on github
https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library/issues/703